# Jixed Bar Too Horozontally

Tags: jquery, plugins

Hi everyone
I am currently doing a chat application and I saw jixedbar which is very suitable to manage multiple chat windows. Unfortunately, when there are too many divs within the jixedbar container element, it hides the additional chat titles with overflow-x: hidden (default jixedbar). I was wondering whether there's an elegant solution to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
body #fixedElement {
    position: fixed !important;
    position: absolute; /*ie6 and above*/
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

From http://snipplr.com/view/2952/ie6-fixed-position-fix/.  Will work in IE6+ and Firefox.  No javascript needed to have your bar at the bottom of the page.

`#fixedElement` is the id of the bar  at the bottom of the page.

EDIT:

`overflow-x: auto !important;`

That would effectively replace the overflow-x:hidden css for that div.  Might be worth a shot.  Just make sure the div is tall enough to handle the scrollbar.

If the divs are nested, that could be an issue.  If they are not nested, this should work.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for: I need to be able to traverse a long list much much longer that what the screen can display.